# 'play' part of my puzzle doesn't return anything

Tags: java, puzzle

the play part of my puzzle doesn't return anything, I've used similar code in other areas which work. i get no errors so i don't know whats wrong, I've tried using '==' and outputting the puzzle separately but again nothing happens. any help would be useful. the puzzle should also use a loop and the game should end when the puzzle is solved but I'm not sure what to use as the before and after, any help here would be useful too.

```
package assignment;

import java.util.Scanner;

import static java.util.Scanner.*;


public class puzzle {

    public static final int N = 4;
    public static final int NUMBER_OF_ROTATIONS = 5;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] puzzle = new int[N][N];
        reset(puzzle);
        test(puzzle);
        reset(puzzle);
        scramble(puzzle);
        System.out.println("### Testing puzzle game play\n");
        play(puzzle);
    }

    public static void print(int[][] puzzle) {
        for (int[] row : puzzle) {
            for (int elem : row) {
                System.out.printf("%4d", elem);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    public static void test(int[][] puzzle) {
        System.out.println("### Testing reset method\n");
        print(puzzle);
        System.out.println("### Testing rotate methods\n");
        print(puzzle);
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            System.out.println("### rotateColumn(" + i + ")\n");
            rotateColumn(puzzle, i);
            print(puzzle);
            System.out.println("### rotateRow(" + i + ")\n");
            rotateRow(puzzle, i);
            print(puzzle);
        }
        reset(puzzle);
        System.out.println("### Testing random rotations\n");
        print(puzzle);
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            randomRotation(puzzle);
            print(puzzle);
        }
    }

    public static void reset(int[][] puzzle) {
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
                puzzle[i][j] = i * N + j;
        }
    }

    public static void scramble(int[][] puzzle) {
        for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_ROTATIONS; i++) {
            randomRotation(puzzle);
        }
    }


    // TODO: Implement method as specified in assignment brief

    public static void rotateRow(int[][] arr, int row) {

        int newRow = arr[row][arr.length - 1];
        int nextRow;
        for (int IndexNo = 0; IndexNo < arr.length; IndexNo++) {
            nextRow = arr[row][IndexNo];
            arr[row][IndexNo] = newRow;
            newRow = nextRow;
        }

    }


    // TODO: Implement method as specified in assignment brief

    public static void rotateColumn(int[][] arr, int column) {
        int newCol = arr[arr.length - 1][column];
        int nextCol;
        for (int IndexNo = 0; IndexNo < arr.length; IndexNo++) {
            nextCol = arr[IndexNo][column];
            arr[IndexNo][column] = newCol;
            newCol = nextCol;
        }
    }


    // TODO: Implement method as specified in assignment brief

    public static void randomRotation(int[][] puzzle) {

        int rowrandom = (int) (Math.random() * 3 + 1);
        int colrandom = (int) (Math.random() * 3 + 1);
        int option = (int) (Math.random() * 2 + 1);

        if (option == 1) {
            rotateRow(puzzle, rowrandom);
        } else {
            rotateColumn(puzzle, colrandom);
        }

    }

    // TODO: Implement method as specified in assignment brief

    static void play(int[][] puzzle) {
        reset(puzzle);
        print(puzzle);

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            randomRotation(puzzle);
        }
        print(puzzle);


        System.out.println("enter row x or col x: ");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String x = input.next();

        if (x.equals("row 0")){
            rotateRow(puzzle, 0);
            print (puzzle);

        }
        if (x.equals("row 1")){
            rotateRow(puzzle, 1);
            print(puzzle);

        }
        if (x.equals("row 2")){
            rotateRow(puzzle, 2);
            print(puzzle);

        }
        if (x.equals("row 3")){
            rotateRow(puzzle, 3);
            print(puzzle);

        }
        if (x.equals("col 0")){
            rotateColumn(puzzle, 0);
            print(puzzle);

        }
        if (x.equals("col 1")){
            rotateColumn(puzzle, 1);
            print(puzzle);

        }
        if (x.equals("col 2")){
            rotateColumn(puzzle, 2);
            print(puzzle);

        }
        if (x.equals("col 3")){
            rotateColumn(puzzle, 3);
            print(puzzle);

        }




    }
}
```

Comment: When you say return some thing are you referring to an actual return value, or are you looking for a print statement, I ask because void has no return type and wont return any thing.

Comment: the method was a template given to us, so i we can't change it, so i don't think we actually use return, i just want the puzzle to be outputted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With regards to the puzzle not showing anything, a `Scanner` will only read the first word if you use the `input.next()` method. To read text with a space (e.g. "row 1"), you need to use `input.nextLine()`

Answer (score 1):

Your play method does not return anything because it is declared `void`, and indeed you don't even have a return statement.

You should declare the method as:

```
static int[][] play(int[][] puzzle) {
    ...
    return puzzle;
}
```

Comment: the method was part of a code template, so i don't think i can change it

Comment: @Cyb3rFly3r I believe the op was simply confused about returning some thing as he has a function specifically for printing this in which case it's pointless to change to int and return. Also op the issue is in your print statement, try using a standard for loop rather than a for each, also get rid of the subscript in your for loop